# Do I need SSDT if I have Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I am learning SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS), so I installed Visual Studio 2017. I'm watching a Udemy course, and it uses SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). Do I really need to install SSDT, or will Visual Studio 2017 Community suffice?  I guess I don't see a difference between them. They seem to serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need both.. in fact.. you can just install MS Report Builder and as long as you have a data source to connect to and work with .. you are good to go.